# scanf inside function to return value (or other function)

Tags: c, input, type-conversion, scanf

so i was going to run a function in an infinite loop which takes a number input, but then I remembered I codn't do

```
while (true) {
    myfunc(scanf("%d));
}
```

because I need to put the scanf input into a variable. I can't do `scanf(%*d)` because that doesn't return value at all. I don't want to have to do

```
int temp;
while (true) {
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    myfunc(temp);
```

or include more libraries. Is there any standard single function like gets (I cod do `myfunc((int) strtol(gets(), (char**) NULL, 10));` but its kinda messy sooo yea)

srry if im asking too much or being pedantic and i shod do ^

btw unrelated question is there any way to declare a string as an int--- or even better, a single function for converting int to string? I usually use

```
//num is some number
char* str = (char*) malloc(12);
sprintf(str, "%d", num);
func(str);
```

but wodnt `func(str(num));` be easier?

Comment: The second block of code is what you need to do.

Comment: op, why would you not want to do as in the second block of code?

Comment: @dbush  I'm pedantic so is there any way to do it in 1 line?

Comment: @ozerodb what I said to dbush

Comment: Condensing code into a single line doesn't necessarily make it more readable.

Comment: Write a function that does it, then call that function in one line.

Comment: Note that [`gets()` is far too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/15168). It is also no longer a part of standard C.

Comment: None of your code variants handle errors in the input or EOF.  Errors will occur (people will type `xyz` where you expected them to type `123`).  You need to handle such situations.

Comment: That's why putting the code in a function is a good idea. You can put all the error checking there, and still have a one-line call.

Comment: im not gonna show this to ppl, this just a prototype for something ill add in a different project

Comment: @JonathanLeffler *fgets()

Comment: What about `fgets()`?  You show a fragment using (misusing!) `gets()`  but that requires an extra variable too.  There's nothing to stop you from writing a function that reads an integer, but you have to handle errors too.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the return value of `scanf` (and similar functions) is the number of conversions that took place. That return value is also used to signify if an error occurred.

In C you must manually manage these errors.

```
if ((retv = scanf("%d", &n)) != 1) {
    /* Something went wrong. */
}
```

What you seem to be looking for are conveniences found in higher-level languages. Languages & runtimes that can hide the details from you with garbage collection strategies, exception nets (`try .. catch`), etc. C is not that kind of language, as by today's standards it is quite a low-level language. If you want "non-messy" functions, you *will* have to build them up from scratch, but you will have to decide what kinds of tradeoffs you can live with.

For example, perhaps you want a simple function that just gets an `int` from the user. A tradeoff you could make is that it simply returns `0` on any error whatsoever, in exchange for never knowing if this *was* an error, or the user actually input `0`.

```
int getint(void) {
    int n;

    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 0;

    return n;
}
```

This means that if a user makes a mistake on input, you have no way of retrying, and the program must simply roll on ahead.

This naive approach scales poorly with the fact that you must manually manage memory in C. It is up to you to `free` any memory you dynamically allocate.

You could certainly write a simple function like

```
char *itostr(int n) {
    char *r = malloc(12);

    if (r && sprintf(r, "%d", n) < 1) {
        r[0] = '0';
        r[1] = '\0';
    }

    return r;
}
```

which does the most minimal of error checking (Again, we don't know if `"0"` is an error, or a valid input).

The problem comes when you write something like `func(itostr(51));`, unless `func` is to be expected to `free` its argument (which would rule out passing non-dynamically allocated strings), you will constantly be leaking memory with this pattern.

So no there is no real "easy" way to do these things. You will have to get "messy" (handle errors, manage memory, etc.) if you want to build anything with complexity.